# How to save camera captured image into app instead of DCIM folder in Android?

Tags: android, all-files

I am newbies here.

I want to develop an app where i want to save Android default camera captured images to my app not on DCIM directory of Android. for that i try solutions is i added All File Permission but Google not approving that permission.

So without All File Access Permission how can i achieve that?

So now i added like when camera capture image we are saving that inside app and also as default system saves it in to DCIM directory. And inside app we added like Duplicate file detection so we can delete duplicate images when user open app.

But i want as like without storing it to DCIM i want to store inside app and without All File Access Permission.

my app functionality is like when you capture image you can save it to your particular pre created folder. Like i am travelling to different cities and i want to arrange my images with folders with cities name then i will just create a folder with current city and now use default camera to capture image and that image only save in that folder.

Comment: One cannot save files in an app. Only save them to a storage location.

Comment: Hi, @blackapps I know that but like my app functionality is like when you capture image you can save it to your particular pre created folder. Like i am travelling to different cities and i want to arrange my images with folders with cities name then i will just create a folder with current city and now use default camera to capture image and that image only save in that folder.

Comment: Then please edit your post. Tell directly what you want. Not something impossible as storing in app. And tell where you wanna save your images. Come to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine is to capture the picture to DCIM and then move or copy the photo to another place. I use this technique to capture and upload pictures, but there is no reason why not to save them to internal (phone) or external (MicroSD) storage.